# Set a String to TextView and wait for a while and set another String to same TextView

Tags: java, android, timedelay

I want to set "First" word to TextView (textTT) and wait for a while set to "Second" to same TextView 
but result is directly set "second" to TextView
but I need firstly set "First". How can I overcome this?
<>

```
private void applicationTest()  {
    textTT.setText("First");
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    textTT.setText("Second");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you call `Thread.sleep(1000)` it means `UI thread`  will be blocking and UI not update `First`. If you want to wait and set `Second` you should use `Handler`. Try this

```
private void applicationTest()  {
    textTT.setText("First");
    new Handler().postDelayed({
           textTT.setText("Second");
    }, 1000)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `thred.sleep` is a very bad practice since you freeze the whole app! So you basically say: set text `first` but do nothing, then set `second`. So you see second. 
Instead you should use `Handler`. In that case you say: set `first` then create a parallel task that waits for 1sec before it executes. After 1 sec it sets `second`.

That is the code for this:

```
private void applicationTest()  {
    textTT.setText("First");
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
          textTT.setText("Second");
       } 
   }, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Handler` to achieve that:

```
private void applicationTest()  {
    textTT.setText("First");
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable{
      @Override
      public void run() {
         textTT.setText("Second");
   } 
    },1000)
}
```